# GEOIP_DATABASE setting is defined, but file does not exist error for django-easy-timezones package

Tags: python, django, django-templates, timezone

I am dynamically trying to change the datetime value in Django templates based on the timezone by using the django-easy-timezones package.

I am referring to the link https://pypi.org/project/django-easy-timezones/

However, the moment I run the django application I get the error:

> GEOIP_DATABASE setting is defined, but file does not exist.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Going by this raise issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Miserlou/django-easy-timezones/issues/18), it seems like the root cause of this error is to do with a packaging problem.

Try to `upgrade/install` the package again. You can also set the paths to the `dat` file explicitly.

```
GEOIP_DATABASE = '/path/to/your/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat'
GEOIPV6_DATABASE = '/path/to/your/geoip/database/GeoLiteCityv6.dat'
```

Obtain the `dat` files [here](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) as mentioned in the documentaiton.

Comment: The issue is still open.  However the files are in the top level directory of the project on GitHub so you can just download them from there.